# Identifying customer first buy on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge database with millions of rows containing transactions information :

```
Client_ID, Date , Product, Price
Jhon, 2022-08-25, google, USD 10,00
Jhon, 2022-09-26, uber, USD 25,00
```

I am trying to create a new dataframe where I can identify monthly, which clients are "new" and which are not, so I wonder to create a new column on my DF containing the date of first buy.

```
Client_ID, Date , Product, Price , Cliente_firt_buy
Jhon, 2022-08-25, google, USD 10,00, 2022-08-25
Jhon, 2022-09-26, uber, USD 25,00, 2022-08-25
```

Something like this, so I could summary my date segregating new and old consumers.

I am struggling how do apply this to the DF.

Thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```py
df.sort_values(['Client_ID','Date'],ascending=True).groupby('Client_ID').first()
```

Comment: Thanks. I used a different way by using the ".min()" instead of first, but you helped me to figure out where to start.